# How to apply formula on whole column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have written a formula for the first cell. It looks like this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF('SHEET2'!B5:B10;SHEET1!A40);INDEX('SHEET2'!E5:E1500; MATCH(A40;'SHEET2'!B5:B10;0)); "")
```

And I want now to apply this formula on whole column. I tried to just pull it down but that did not work because then all of numbers in my formula increase for 1. I don't want this. I want just number "A40" in my formula to increase. How can I do this?

Comment: You need to use absolute addressing for the cells you don't want to change: `=IF(COUNTIF('SHEET2'!$B$5:$B$10;SHEET1!A40);INDEX('SHEET2'!$E$5:$E$1500; MATCH(A40;'SHEET2'!$B$5:$B$10;0)); "")`.

Comment: also have a look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9